# How to position elements in android xml design?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm building a fork of the mesaging app Signal that has a complete backup function instead of the crippled-down one it has now. The functionality works, however, after the design of the UI changed in Signal 4.0 I can't get it correct. All files that I changed from the original source  [can be found here](https://mega.nz/#!5cBm1AgQ!seCCucUBTQrn9lwp3xrLFD-5OCd-yEhDSKypx1BYyY0) . The issue is with the import_export_fragment.xml file. The original file is:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="8dip">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="@string/import_export_fragment__import"
                          android:textSize="20sp"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/import_sms"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?import_sms"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_system_sms_database"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_the_database_from_the_default_system"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/import_plaintext_backup"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?plaintext_backup"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_plaintext_backup"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_a_plaintext_backup_file"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="@string/import_export_fragment__export"
                          android:textSize="20sp"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/export_plaintext_backup"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?plaintext_backup"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/export_fragment__export_plaintext_backup"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/export_fragment__export_a_plaintext_backup_compatible_with"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

I changed the layout to include blocks for encrypted backup/restore:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:padding="8dip">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="@string/import_export_fragment__import"
                          android:textSize="20sp"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/import_sms"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?import_sms"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_system_sms_database"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_the_database_from_the_default_system"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/import_plaintext_backup"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?plaintext_backup"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_plaintext_backup"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__import_a_plaintext_backup_file"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/import_encrypted_backup"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?encrypted_backup"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__restore_encrypted_backup"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/import_fragment__restore_a_previously_exported_encrypted_signal_backup"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         android:padding="20dp">

                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:text="@string/import_export_fragment__export"
                          android:textSize="20sp"/>

            </FrameLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/export_plaintext_backup"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?plaintext_backup"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/export_fragment__export_plaintext_backup"/>

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/export_fragment__export_a_plaintext_backup_compatible_with"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/gray10"/>

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/export_encrypted_backup"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="8dip"
                          android:paddingBottom="8dip"
                          android:layout_marginLeft="16dip"
                          android:layout_marginRight="16dip">

                <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                           android:layout_marginEnd="10dip"
                           android:src="?encrypted_backup"/>

                <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              style="@style/Registration.Description"
                              android:text="@string/export_fragment__export_encrypted_backup"/>


                    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent"
                              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                              android:gravity="start"
                              android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                              android:text="@string/export_fragment__export_an_encrypted_backup_to_the_sd_card"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

But this made the header fall off the screen:

[Changed UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8mqp.jpg)

I have no idea why this happens. I can correct the issue so the user sees all elements by adding a line

'

```
android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
```

'

to the first cardview, however, this results in borders who increase when the device screen resolution increases: on a low-end device it looks about right at the top, on a device with a higher resolution I get too much whitespace at the top.

And at the bottom I get a too large area too.

So my question is: what am I missing, and how do I make the UI noce for all screen resolutions?

Comment: Please show the a screenshot of the original layout

Comment: try (android:layout_marginTop="160dp") on the ScrollView -- although normally the plain Toolbar is 56dp height as shown here https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing

Comment: The original layout is at https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUQ7g.jpg . I wanted to post more pictures but the system said I was limited to 2 links.